# Swift - SKSpriteNode missing from scene at default position

Tags: swift, skspritenode

I setup my project as Language: Swift, Game Technology: SpriteKit, Device iPhone and I can't seem to figure out why at default position my node is not added to the (0,0) position of the scene.

**GameScene.swift**

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

   let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")

   override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

       self.addChild(ball)

   }
}
```

When I position the ball at the center of the screen using below command, then it appears.

```
self.ball.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2)
```

I tried to add add physics body to the scene, but it didn't make much of a difference.

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
```

Please advise why by default my nodes are not added at (0,0) position of the scene as they supposed to. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this In GameViewController.swift:

```
scene.size = skView.bounds.size
```

Just before:

```
skView.presentScene(scene)
```